# Link child to button working in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I can not figure out why this is happening. I have a link that is a child element to a button, and it is supposed to bring you to a different part of the page when it is activated. The link works in Chrome, but when I try and load the page on Internet Explorer, the links don't work. This is my HTML and CSS for this part of the site:

HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;float:right;display: inline-block;">
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="q" size="25"
maxlength="255" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</form>

<div id="score_container">
    <button id="cubs_score"><a href="#scoring_widget">How are the Cubs Doing?</a></button>
    <button id="packers_score"><a href="#scoring_widget">How are the Packers Doing?</a></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cubs_score{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #CC3433 !important;
    background-color: #0E3386;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#packers_score{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #FFB612 !important;
    background-color: #203731;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
text-decoration: none;
}

#score_container{
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 2;
   color: inherit;
}
```

The versions of IE that I have checked in are 10 and 11.

Comment: Links as children of buttons is invalid HTML

Comment: Can you post the html for your scoring widget? Are you using any JS for the jump or just plain HTML? CSS would most likely not have anything to do with this.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that. Is there any way that I could use a div but make it have the same neat visual effects of a button? @j08691

Comment: I wouldn't make a div have the visual effects, but I think a link would be great. You can add hover and click css to a link, so you can make them have all sorts of visual effects.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Phrasing_content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) can contain

> <a>, if it contains only phrasing content.

So it is not an error.

But there is a different behaviour between the two browsers, so I added some jQuery code:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#score_container button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location.hash = this.childNodes[0].getAttribute('href');
  });
});
```

```css
#cubs_score{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #CC3433 !important;
  background-color: #0E3386;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#packers_score{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #FFB612 !important;
  background-color: #203731;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#score_container{
  width: 310px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 2;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;float:right;display: inline-block;">
        <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
            <tr><td>
                <input type="text"   name="q" size="25"
                       maxlength="255" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" value="Google Search" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
            </td></tr></table>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="score_container">
    <button id="cubs_score"><a href="#scoring_widget1">How are the Cubs Doing?</a></button>
    <button id="packers_score"><a href="#scoring_widget2">How are the Packers Doing?</a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you were wondering how to style a button to have cool effects like a link. Here is an example of that:

```css
#link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #006400;
  transition: background-color.2s, color .2s;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #006400;
  transition: background-color.2s, color .2s;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #006400;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: background-color.2s, color .2s;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #056905;
  background-color: #EEE;
  transition: background-color.2s, color .2s;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Hope that this helps you finish your project!